# JSON API in wordpress

Tags: ios, json, wordpress, authentication

this is my first time to create a mobile app that using wordpress as webserver
i already find a way to send post data into mobile app (in my case i'm using iOS) using JSON API (wordpress plugin) but is there a way to do register or login on mobile app ?
and how to do that ?

Comment: is there a reason you are using a plugin? let alone one that hasnt been maintained over 2 years??

Comment: there's no special reason, i use that API because i found many articles refers to that API, and how can we do that manually ? can you give me some tutorial or something else that can help me, thanks

Comment: can you clarify what you need to achieve from wordpress on mobile?

Comment: i need the mobile app can show the page/post(include the comment and author name) from wordpress, and the last is register and login function. btw is it possible ?, because i did some research but all i found is for login and no result for register.

Comment: are you making a mobile app, thats hybrid or just a responsive app?

Comment: i'm thinking about make a native application for iphone using objective c and JSON for getting data through wordpress (i don't know it is in category of hybrid or something else)

Comment: why not make a hybrid, so basically its a wordpress app inside of a native wrapper to post to the iOS and android stores with something like phone gap

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a solution to this.

My current thinking is an ugly hack. I would send a request to wp-login.php with the username and pasword and check if you are redirected away from wp-login.php, and if so, store something in localStorage telling the app that it was able to login successfully.

It is a bit ugly but it may just work.

Comment: wow thanks man, is it working ?, i can use this for backup plan

Answer (score 0):

You could use the wordpress custom page templates to make a JSON api for logged in users. for example:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Logged-in users
*/
?>

{
<?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
"users": {
"logged-in": "true"
}
<?php } else { ?>
"users": {
"logged-in": "false"
}
<?php } ?>
}
```

Afterwards you can include a web view in your application, displaying the login page of your WordPress website. Then you could refresh the JSON api url every 10 seconds to see if the user had logged in or not. While the value is true for logged-in, the user will be able to use the app. Also you could use this method to create user specific api for the current logged in user by sharing cookies. Hope this helps!